# How to find Inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{\alpha + j\omega}$

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis

I know if we apply Fourier transform to $f(t) =  \begin{cases}0,& t<0\\ e^{-\alpha t} &t>0  \end{cases} $, we get $F(\omega) = \frac{1}{\alpha+j\omega}$.

But how to get from $F(\omega)$ to $f(t)$ ?, because after writing the formula:
$$f(t)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\alpha + j\omega}e^{j\omega t} d\omega$$ I cannot get any further. The integral seems hard to solve, as $\omega$ is in the denominator, being in the numerator it would be easy integration by parts. And also, how do I tell that the final result will have different definitions for the positive and negative parts of the real numbers.

Comment: You can try to use a change of variable to compute the integral by setting $X=\alpha+j\omega$ then $d\omega = -jdX$ and $j\omega t=(X-\alpha)t$ The integral becomes :$$f(t)=\frac{-j}{2\pi}\int_{\alpha-j\infty}^{\alpha+j\infty}\frac{1}{X}e^{(X-\alpha)t}dX$$

Comment: Thanks for you comment. But after that change, $X$ remains in the denominator, and I don't see a way to solve that integral either.

Comment: $j \omega \mapsto j \omega - \alpha$ and then use that the resulting integral is $\text{sgn}(t)$.